# Asking Meta users vs using Contact Us button?

Tags: discussion, meta, contact

If I have a query  about the workings of SE sites, or other related issues, I can ask here on Meta or use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button.

Are there specific instances where is it better to contact one or the other?

Are some of the people involved here the same people that will answer via the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) button?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Are you asking if there is a difference in the audience you reach out to between posting a question here on Meta and using the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link? I ask because I don't know of a feature that you can contact the Help center, as you state in your question. You might want clarify that with an [edit].

Comment: How are you planning to contact the [help]?  Or do you mean refer to the [help]?

Comment: @PolyGeo - I mean this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact, or any analogous link for each SE site.

Answer (score 7):

You don't *contact* the help center. It's a periodically updated and static resource of essential information of the running of the site. It is stuff that's necessary to know.

As such the help center should typically have most common issues - in a sense, it's your first port of call, and for the most part, is *mostly* standard across the network. You should always read it first, and for the most part, it's maintained by the folks who run the network. When in doubt, it's also pretty much the 'canonical' rules of the site and provides the backbone of how we do things.

Sometimes though, the "standard" problems aren't yours. Sometimes sites have their own culture or decided to do things a certain way. If it is not covered on the Help page, either because it's specific (like how certain classes of questions should be handled) or doesn't quite fit into the help pages, it should be on meta.

I tend to use a legal analogy here - Help's the statutes and are immutable , meta's case law and is often the interpretation of the rules. We also have some local laws (per site metas) that don't always affect things outside a specific site.

So, if it's a question on a *specific* site it, goes on their meta. If it's a question on the network as a whole, not covered by previous questions or the help center, it can be asked here.

Meta's handled by the communities - though we often reference back to posts here or other meta. I'd probably have a better idea how things work on SuperUser than say, Shog9. On the other hand, Shog9 and other CMs are probably more of an authoritative source here.

So it's different people, but chances are you'll find someone who knows what's what on the *right site*.

I'd reserve the "contact us" for *very* serious matters you don't think a moderator can handle - a quick look at the drop down gives you an idea of what it is for.

[image]

I personally think some of those should be handleable on site (like the QA related ones) but essentially the contact us is for when you'd need someone who *works for Stack Exchange* to take a look at something. I've personally only needed it a handful of times, and a good chunk of the time I point people at it for a user profile merger.

Comment: FWIW, several of those options are pretty clearly just honeypots for someone to politely say "We have taken your feedback into consideration!" before "considering" the message into the round file.